# Ruby string with a null byte

Tags: ruby, string, arrays

I have this class:

```
class CountedOctet
  attr_reader :length, :data
  def initialize
    @length = nil
    @data = ""
  end
  def parsefile(f)
    @length, = f.read(4).unpack("N")
    @data, = f.read(@length).unpack("a#{@length}")
  end
end
```

It's ported from https://github.com/rvazarkar/KrbCredExport (which is in Python) to Ruby.

Everything works fine, the files gets read, but if I access data it gets cut off. The length of it is 1163 (which is correct), but at position 152 the byte of the string is 0. This seems to terminate the string. Position 153 is correct, so the reading and unpacking seems to have worked correct. Is there any way to stop Ruby from terminating the string at the null byte?

The python script works with the same file, so it shouldn't be a corrupt/wrong file.

Comment: which ruby version are you using?

Comment: @tompave I'm using 1.9.3

Comment: Where did you get this string from? utf-8 strings never have zero byte in the middle.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I'm porting a python script into Ruby. I get the string trough file.read(@length).unpack("a#{length}").

Comment: What kind of file is that? Binary? Byte array is rarely also a valid string.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yes it's a binary file. I got the byte values through debugging the program which shows me the terminated string and the byte values of the string array. In the python script it works, so the file is correct.

Comment: I know you don't want to share the data file but is it possible to share more or the whole code instead of single lines? Is using `@length` but also `length` intended? Why are you using `String#unpack` here?

Comment: @cremno I've edited the question to give the class I'm using and the context.

Comment: `f.read(@length)` already gives you a binary string. No need to use `unpack('a*')` on top of that.

Comment: @NicNilov I know. But I want data to be a string. Not a binary String. In the Python script the output from read gets packes into a string as well, for writing it back to a file later.

Comment: Yes, but you do have non-ascii/unicode characters in it. Is it cleanup what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @NicNilov I know that. But Python seems to be able to handle that. So my question is, why Ruby seems to have problems with the same string.

The purpose of the script is to extract data from the ccache file (where Kerberos tickets are stored) and save them in a .kirbi file, which has a certain structure.

Comment: `if I access data it gets cut off` - We need to see that part of the code and not one that works as expected.

Comment: Ruby is not Python just like Python is not Ruby. You have binary file, so a binary string is what you get. It's not clear what handling you are trying to do before saving that to another (binary?) file. You probably should handle the data as binary as well instead of trying to convert it to a character string.

Comment: @cremno I'm debugging with Aptana Studio 3. I have a breakpoint after I've parsed the file. When I access data, it shows me the wrong string.

Comment: That sounds like Aptana Studio 3 has a bug. Or can you reproduce it with the good old `p` debugging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was, that I used `''` for my string. With `""` the zero Byte was interpreted correctly.